# Why do I have to specifically import ldap.modlist?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ldap

What is so special about `ldap.modlist` that I have to explicitly import it?  Importing `ldap` is not enough:

```
>>> import ldap
>>> ldap.modlist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'modlist'
```

But if I explicitly import it, then all is well:

```
>>> import ldap
>>> import ldap.modlist
>>> ldap.modlist
<module 'ldap.modlist' from '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/modlist.pyc'>
```

Why?  Other modules don't behave like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>

>>> import ldap
>>> ldap.dn
<module 'ldap.dn' from '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/dn.pyc'>
```

Comment: That's not special; that's how all packages behave.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I just edited the question to include a contrast between `ldap.modlist` and `os.path`.  Can you address this?  Does the term _package_ have some specific technical meaning?

Comment: Indeed, it is os.path that is special. On packages, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package).

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but the docs didn't seem to explain this difference.  What is the mechanism by which `foo.bar` is not accessible after importing `foo`, but `foo.baz` is?

Comment: As specific examples, see `ldap.modlist` and `ldap.dn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the modules `ldap.dn` and `ldap.modlist` is this:

The module `ldap.dn` is loaded during the initialization of the `ldap` package and is therefore already present as an attribute in the `ldap` package (see [The Import System: Submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) for a description about submodules):

```
# ldap/__init__.py, line 89 of python-ldap version 2.4.27
from ldap.dn import explode_dn,explode_rdn,str2dn,dn2str
```

The module `ldap.modlist` on the other hand is not loaded during the initalization of the `ldap` package.

Comment: Aha!  That's the piece I was missing.  I went over `__init__.py` with a fine-tooth comb looking for `import dn`, but I missed the `from ldap.dn import ...`